# a single database for 2 apps: desktop and android

Tags: java, android, database

I've searched throw your many posts but I didn't find the answer to my question.
I want to make a project which involves two applications: a desktop one written in java, on the pc and the other in android that will be on a mobile phone. I would like to connect both of the applications to a single database but I don't know were to start it from and how to do it.
Could you give me an example or a hint please? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: do you want the same java source code for both but with different database instances? or do you want to have one database instance for both?

Comment: one common database...both apps have to connect to the same database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to run your desktop in different PC than the database, if yes, than on the database site you can do a minimal PHP which will be the server with database connection. You can find many php + mysql free hosting. Many php examples are  how to receive a GET and a POST parameters, connect to database and return results. Use that server side for serving both mobiles and desktops. So the Communication is via HTTP POST and HTTP GET. Distributed applications like this are used in commercial environments and in school usually you can get a little better note. Google it for keywords implementations. Good luck.

Comment: thank you very much...I really hope I can do this. But the android app needs to connect to the server throw wireless or usb or will this work without?

Comment: Android will connect to Internet with  usb, wireless, 3g, whatever... Google: "android how to do a HTTP POST" tell me if you didn't got any example, but I am sure it is over 1 million